# Python Roster optimizer

Tags: python, optimization, knapsack-problem

I am trying to build a python program to optimize a fantasy sports roster.  I have looked into scipy and am throughly confused about how to tackle the problem.  The problem is to maximize the expected amount of points for a roster, constrained to one of each player position.  Additionally, each player has a salary, and the sum of all the players salaries is also constrained.  So in short, I would like to choose the combination of players to maximize the expected points, while not exceeding the salary cap.

I initially started to do this using nested loops, but it would take an extreme amount of time.

Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Here is an example of the data, in a pandas dataframe.

```
    Position    Name    Salary  AvgPointsPerGame
    0   PG  Russell Westbrook   13200   54.004
    1   SG  James Harden        11500   49.982
    2   PF  Anthony Davis       11200   49.594
    3   SF  LeBron James        10100   47.861
    4   PG  Chris Paul          9900    44.278
    5   C   DeMarcus Cousins    9600    49.477
    6   SF  Kevin Durant        9500    43.481
    7   PF  Blake Griffin       8900    41.705
    8   PF  LaMarcus Aldridge   8800    42.816
    9   PF  Pau Gasol           8700    42.250
    10  PG  John Wall           8600    41.722
    11  C   DeAndre Jordan      8300    37.342
    12  SG  Eric Bledsoe        8200    37.132
    .....
```

I am looking into the knapsack problem as suggested... any advice on modifying this code to 1)restrict the size of the bag to 6, and 2) limit each position to a maximum of 2 spots.  Thanks for the help.

```
def knapsack(items, limit):
table = [[0 for w in range(limit + 1)] for j in xrange(len(items) + 1)]

for j in xrange(1, len(items) + 1):
    pos, name, cost, val = items[j-1]
    for w in xrange(1, limit + 1):
        if cost > w:
            table[j][w] = table[j-1][w]
        else:
            table[j][w] = max(table[j-1][w], table[j-1][w-cost] + val)

result = []
w = limit
for j in range(len(items), 0, -1):
    was_added = table[j][w] != table[j-1][w]

    if was_added:
        pos, name, cost, val = items[j-1]
        result.append(items[j-1])
        w -= wt

return result
```

Comment: This is a variation of the [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). You should read up on that.

Answer (score 1):

I use my own genetic algorithm for this problem.  I won't spell it out completely as there are a lot of small details, but here's enough to get started:

1. Create a function which picks a team at random
2. Create a function which, given a team, checks if it's valid (salary cap)
3. Create a function which scores the team
4. Create a function which creates a new team given two teams (mates)
5. Start by picking ten random teams
6. Take the top 3 teams and mate to have a total of 6 teams
7. Pick 3 more teams completely at random, for a total of 9 teams
8. Rank, sort, repeat

You should converge in under a minute.

The secret sauce is in the mating function.  When mating teams A and B at position X, you'll have a set of players to pick randomly from.  To that set, add another player completely at random.  Another point: when you mate and check the salary cap and it fails, just choose one of the parent teams to be the child.

Comment: can you explain a little more about what you mean 'Create a function which creates a new team given two teams (mates)'.  Create a new team at random to compare to?

Comment: or do you mean use the player sets from the team to create a new random team?

Comment: Input: Team X, Team Y.  Output: Team Z which is a mixture of players from X and Y.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I think i am getting there.  Sorry for all the questions, but I am new at this.  You say that it should converge in under a minute, so I guess you do this recusively... so what do you use as your base case?

Comment: Step 5 -- pick ten random teams.  Recursive is probably not the right word.  After a while, the new teams you get in the current iteration will not beat the teams you already have.  That happens pretty quickly.

Comment: Pete, thanks so much for outlining your approach! I've successfully implemented it in Python. In my experience it converges after only 100-200 iterations. I've also had some good success in rerunning the process many times and getting a crop of good lineups. Finally, culling the source list of players also helps quite a bit (for example, only keeping the top player for a particular price point). Anyway, great approach, fast, and fascinating!